# android memory monitor - "cause GC"

Tags: android

I used android tool `"memory monitor"` to fix memory leaks. It helps.

However, I need one clarification.

Sometime after running the app,  allocated memory is "47MB". It goes up and down while app is interacted with.

Then when I click `"cause GC"`, allocated memory goes down to "30MB".

If I click it again, it goes to "17MB". My app started with 17MB.

Why do I need to click "cause GC" **twice** to reclaim all the memory?

Or is this unexpected and I should be clicking only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the set of objects on the heap before and after each cycle might tell you more about what is going on.  It could be due to GC policy decisions (say, a generational collector not scanning all generations), or it could be due to the way objects reference each other.

One possible scenario has to do with finalization and native pointers.  Suppose a bitmap object has a native component, and that native component has a JNI global reference to another object (perhaps a `byte[]` with the pixel data).  The first GC would free the bitmap.  Shortly after the GC completes, the bitmap's finalizer would run, releasing the JNI global ref.  However, the `byte[]` will still be on the heap until the next GC pass notices that it's no longer referenced.

(This is how Bitmaps were actually handled by the Skia library until "Ice Cream Sandwich" or thereabouts.)

Comment: @user2384694 Yes. Dalvik will start running GC vigorously if it detects a huge shortage in memory. That is when your app (and other apps too) will start to 'hang'.

Comment: It depends. If it's a question of GC policy, the GC will do absolutely everything it can to release memory before throwing an OOM. If unfinalized objects are causing problems, you could have a problem -- finalizers must run on a separate thread, independent of the GC, so the managed heap can't sit and wait for them to run. Generally speaking, the GC will thrash a bit before you get to OOM, which should allow finalizers to complete, and there shouldn't be any crazy native-refs-to-big-buffers left in the app framework itself.